# Searching content in custom module of Orchard CMS doesn't work

Tags: orchardcms

I wrote my own module for Orchard CMS. Module have some widgets, for example,one of widgets is a news widget. In Admin menu(Content->Content Type) I checked Index this content type for search, but when I try to search anything in my widget, nothing found. For searching I use standart widget, which part of Orchard CMS. I know that Orchard use Lucene.net, and there are my questions:

- How Lucene.net index content of all pages ?
- What I need to implement in my module(widgets) for searching ?

Answer (score 1):

A widget is not routable, so it can't appear in search results.

Comment: Don't you know, how can I pass this constraint ?

Comment: What do you mean constraint? Index content types that have the route part and they will appear in search results.